# Paste (dynamic) lookup formula in dynamic number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet "2018" and "2019" which i created previously. 2019 only differs from 2018 in that it may have some rows added and/or some deleted.
Form Cell "A3" and downwards i have skills listed and a "X" in the columns after if the person the column belongs to has this skill.

Now i need to fill the columns of 2019 with known X with formula below, first a bit of context code for the range selection part:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngbegin As Range
Dim rngend As Range
Dim newrng As Range

Sheets("2018").Activate

   Set rng = Application.InputBox '...and rest of the code

rng.Copy
Sheets("2019").Range("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Sheets(2019).Activate
Set rngbegin = rng.Cells(3, 1)
Set rngend = rng.Cells(3000, rng.Columns.Count)
Set newrng = Range(rngbegin.Address & ":" & rngend.Address)
newrng.ClearContents 'To clear everything in the difined range but the headder rows
```

Here is a formula i could use if the columns wouldn't be varying.

> ```
> Range("B3").Select
> ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A3='2018'!$A$3:D$5000),'2018'!$B$3:$B$5000),"")"
>     Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
> ```

The Formula works but i have the following problems:
**1 - Required**) I can't hardcode the formula for every column because the number of colums may change. (I store the number of columns as range var selected from the user via application.inputbox - that's how i inserted the colums in the new 2019 sheet)

2 - optional) I hardcoded the rows to a much higher number than are used because i didn't thnk of counting Column A and then use the range.count.Address(?) as end of the search vector. Just came into my mind lol

Comment: What are `rng1` and `rng2` here?

Comment: Sorry forgot to change variables.Corrected.

Comment: Steer clear from `.Activate` makes your code run slow. To clear contents simply use `Sheets("2019").Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.ClearContents`

Comment: To find the last used column in row 1 try `Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: With your code i would clear the whole rows from 3 downwards, but with my  code i copy columns with contents (X's). While i need the headers, i don't need the filled out X because they are false if simply copied (row contents of Column "A" may have changed.) so i saw no other way than to create a new range out of the user selected range (Column:Column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to tweak a few addresses.  I left much of your code unchanged so you can easily adapt what I have came up with for your purposes.

```
Sub Whatever()

With Sheets("2018")

    ' Get the address of the old range, not used later in the macro
    iRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    iCols = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rngOld = Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(iRows, iCols))

End With

With Sheets("2019")

    ' Get the address of the new range
    iRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    iCols = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set rngNew = Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(iRows, iCols))

    'Clear the new range
    rngNew.Clear

    ' Populate the formula
    ' Not very elegant, VBA solution would probably look nicer
    .Range("B3").Formula = "=IFERROR(if(LOOKUP(2,1/('2018'!$A$3:$A$" & iRows & " =$A3),'2018'!B$3:B$" & iRows & ")=""X"",""X"",""""),"""")"

    'Fill the formula
    Set rngTemp = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(3, iCols))
    rngTemp.FillRight
    Set rngTemp = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(iRows, iCols))
    rngTemp.FillDown

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Michal,
unfortunately your solution deletes whole rows and not the user defined range + all the way down. Same with formula.

I created a screenshot to show my needs:
https://picload.org/view/dcolclcg/problemstellung.png.html

Comment: As I said in my original post - you will possibly need to tweak a few addresses to make it work.  You have already done a lot of good work, might as well try to finish it by yourself :)  Cheers, Michal

Comment: I tweaked the cells addresses in the above and it works as requested.  Cheers,

Comment: Okay, i'll try it :)

Comment: Minor edit to make it perfect.. hope it works for you.  Cheers, Michal

Comment: Hi, i already tweaked everything were just working on the if implementation as you edited :D

Everything works now but somehow when i set the rngtemp to fill right, it counts  the correct number of columns but the last column is left out. I worked around it as i just count colums.count + 1 but i am curious.

<pre>
'Fill the formula
        Set rngtemp = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(3, rng.Columns.Count + 1))
        rngtemp.Select
        rngtemp.FillRight
        Set rngtemp = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(irows, rng.Columns.Count))
        rngtemp.FillDown
<code<

Comment: one more questioned: can i color the row where the iferror throws an error so i can see which entries do not exist in the 2018 sheet and therefore see which entries are new.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - just use Conditional Formatting.  No need to VBA when there are already built in tools that do just that.  ~~~~

Comment: The question is how? Conditional Formatting doesn't see when an error occurs because i set it to output nothing (""") when an error occurs.